# Fix the transparency of glass shader in cycle render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency, glass

I've had glass shader transparency issues where there is a punched hole in the lens during cycle render, please answer my question right now.

[image]

I've read a few questions regarding the cycle rendering time transparency issues, but they're all in older versions. I'm using Blender 3.0.1 and [here's my .blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-JbaHMrnRrs9ZbmlS_w5ANkUsjS85dgC/view?usp=sharing):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you set a check to "shadow catcher" on Glass.lens.

If you uncheck it, you will get:

[image]

I moved it a bit just so you can see the difference.

Comment: I've moved first the problem are in the glass lens and turned on the shadow catcher too, but the holes still appear again.

Comment: i am not sure what you mean by "moved the first problem" but can you please upload your edited blend file again so that i can have a look at it?

Comment: Oh I mean, I've set the shadow catcher tick but there's still appear hole again

Comment: that's why i wrote: uncheck the shadow catcher ;)

Comment: Check or uncheck is the same a hole appear again, but where else is the problem.

Comment: you have some issues with your model. You have double vertices, which you can solve by selecting all vertices and pressing M -> merge by distance. Also your blend file has often checked "selectable off" which makes it a bit hard to work with. you can see your double vertices pretty clear here: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIsfT.png. If unchecking shadow catcher does still not work you might want to download the newest 3.0 version ( i tried it with mine and it worked)

Comment: I've had glass shader transparency issues where there is a punched hole in the Glass.Lens during cycle render, please answer my question right now.

Comment: did you try my answer with the newest version? Please make a video of what you tried so i can see what you did, then i can help you.